# Install latest version of rsync (3.2.3) on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

It seems the last version for ubuntu 18.04 is rsync 3.1.2 (with !apt-get --only-upgrade install rsync).

Is there a way I can update it to the latest? (preferably 3.2.1+) Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software). Why do you need a different version? What feature is missing from your current software? Are you experiencing any problems?

Comment: For close voters. OP does not ask "Why it is old?". OP asks "How to install newer version?".

Comment: @Nmath The old version is very buggy. I even ended up reporting a solved issue to the devs, eventually finding out that the issue was already fixed on later versions. 
https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/232

After that, I managed to update by some non-standard method, which is not working anymore, thus asking this question.

Finally, N0rbert's solution is very easy and works like charm. I should've asked this question long ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install newer rsync (*3.2.3-8ubuntu1~18.04.sav0*) from [Rob Savoury's Utilities PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/utilities?field.series_filter=bionic) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:savoury1/utilities
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rsync
```

Reverting to default version is possible by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:savoury1/utilities
```

Comment: I had to run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:savoury1/utilities` twice for it to downgrade rsync back to the default version

Comment: Works for 16.04 too. Thanks